# Zen of Python printing in console without `import this`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The Zen of Python randomly started printing in my console after running my SCRIPT. I can't recall exactly what updates I made to cause this change.

I'm running a multi-file Python bot, so it's a bit more complicated to track every single import, but a quick `import this` search on the directory with VSCode does not show any occurrences of it.

Is there a way to see where exactly or which line/import is causing the print to debug this?

I'm using Python 3.10.5, Windows on VSCode (though I don't think this matters as I tried running in IDLE and same thing happens).

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve]? If we can't reproduce the issue, there's no way for us to help you.

Comment: @SuperStormer presumably if they could make a reproducible example, they'd have their answer already.

Comment: One of the big benefits of using source control is you don't need to "recall" what changes you made, you have a record of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that it is indeed caused by an `import this`, you could temporarily edit the `this` module (at Python3x/Lib/this.py) and add a `breakpoint()`, then print the stack trace (`where` if using pdb) and figure out exactly where it was imported from.

Comment: Nice idea. My 2 cents: it might be useful to add some more details on how to implement it executive (a quick example of where to add the breakpoint, even if it doesn't matter, and of quick instructions on how to use the debugger). If OP was familiar with the debugger they probably would have done it already?

Comment: I thought about including a code sample, but like you said the position wouldn't matter, so it didn't really feel helpful. Similar for the debugger since it will give you a pretty clear prompt to type into.